# Mat type data in C++ (opencv) as same as the image_to_array after using python preprocessing?

Tags: python, c++, opencv, python-imaging-library

I'm working on convert the python code to C++, I got a data structure problems about `Mat` in OpenCV (C++ version) and `image preprocessing` in Python.

Python code is following:

```
img = image.load_img(img_path)
img = img.resize((d_widght, d_height), image.NEAREST).convert('RGB')
img = image.img_to_array(img)
```

and the result of the img after 'image.img_to_array' is a three dimension array 3*384.

C++ code is following here:

```
Mat img = imread('1.jpg');
Mat imgdst;
resize(img, imgdst,Size(384,384)); 
//because the image size after resize in python is (384*384), so here I just convert the image size using this line.
```

Then, the `'imgdst'` is same as the `'img'` in python, which is a `3*384` array?

Answer (score 0):

yes imgdst is the same as img, even in c++ you may

```
Mat img = imread('1.jpg');
resize(img, img,Size(384,384));
```

Comment: emm, I means.. the data structure of img in python is 3*384, however, i just print the data out in C++, its seems like a 384*384 array..

Comment: actually no, all images, RGB at least, will have the shape (384,384,3), I'm not sure how PIL does it, but I think it loads the image in shape(3,384,384), as per your observations. Even if there's a difference in shape, you could always transpose them

Comment: @BomerLawrence You are confusing dimensions, you wrote "three dimension array 3*384", three dimension array have **3** dimensions, so in both Python and C++ it's 3*384*384.

Comment: also, why not just use open cv in python as well? the code will be an almost exact copy in python

Comment: @sklott， yes, sorry, its 384*384*3

Comment: @ImtinanAzhar emmm C++ have better performance on speed I think....I would like to use Python, however, I can't decide it ...

Comment: I agree c++ is faster, but my question isn't that why are you using python not c++, my question is why arent you sing OpenCV in python as well? If you arent aware then opencv is available in python as well